# Arrow functions with call/apply/bind

Tags: javascript, web, ecmascript-6, debouncing

Mozilla Developer Network states that `call`, `bind` and `apply` should not be used with arrow functions. Makes sense since they take the context of the parent from the place they are defined and use that themselves.

Now, below is some code for "debounce" I have seen in a few videos. Does using `apply` even do something here?

```js
const getData = () => {

}

const debounce = function(fn, d) {
    let timer;
    return function() {
        let context = this,
        args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            fn.apply(context, arguments);
        }, d);
    }
}
```

EDIT : Changed getData to fn inside the debounce function.

Comment: As arrow functions don't bind this, you can't use bind, call, or apply to change the "context". Instead use a "regular" function. --- Edit: the methods can still be used to change the arguments

Comment: `.apply()`, `.call()`, and `.bind()`, work the same with arrow functions *aside from* not changing the value of `this`. A lot of times `this` isn't used, so it doesn't matter much whether you call `f.apply(context, arguments)` on an arrow function or not. If it *does* matter, then you need to make sure `f` is a regular function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `context` argument does nothing (because it sets `this` and you can't do that to an arrow function).

The `arguments` array does get applied though.

If you were writing code specifically for the arrow function then the idiomatic way would be to spread the arguments instead:

```
getData(...arguments);
```

---

In this particular context the `debounce` function can handle any kind of function passed into `fn` (and you should be using `fn` not `getData` inside the timeout).

If you pass in a non-arrow function then the returned function will have `this` work as normal.

If you pass in an arrow function then the returned function will have `this` *not* be changed (but also as normal!).

Comment: Thanks. I was almost confident that it will not have any effect, but I had seen it in some videos and got confused.